# HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP in Eclipse with the Date method

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I'm using Eclipse Kepler.
I keep getting an error message with this code in a .jsp:

HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

---

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Syntax error on token "import", delete this token
10: 
11: 
12: 
13: <% page import ="java.util.Date" %>
14: 
15: <%= new Date () %>
16:

An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
10: 
11: 
12: 
13: <% page import ="java.util.Date" %>
14: 
15: <%= new Date () %>
16:

An error occurred at line: 15 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
Date cannot be resolved to a type
12: 
13: <% page import ="java.util.Date" %>
14: 
15: <%= new Date () %>
16: 
17: 
18:

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.

---

### Apache Tomcat/7.0.42

There is the code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>



<% page import ="java.util.Date" %>

<%= new Date () %>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a wrong syntax, you are missing "@".

Comment: Thank you but where am I missing the "@"?

Comment: I found it , its here:<%@ page.